# React js "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" and many javascript errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having issues with  reacts javascript part is there anything that can solve this issues permanently

```
function Header() {
    
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = "250px";
      }
      
      function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = "0";
      }
    return (
        <nav className="Header">
            <img className="logo" src="./assets/logo.png" alt=""/>
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="closebtn" onClick={closeNav()}>&times;</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Header
```

ı was just trying to make aburger menu and this happened please help.

Comment: This is not very react-esque style of coding. Consider using refs to refer to components instead of `getElementById` and using inline styles and state to update the width instead of manipulating the html element directly.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly manipulate styles like this in React.

Comment: Don't manually change DOM elements. Why use react otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are prematurely calling `closeNav()`.

The issue is on this line:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" className="closebtn" onClick={closeNav()}>&times;</a>
```

change it to be this so that `closeNav` only gets called when the button is clicked:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" className="closebtn" onClick={() => closeNav()}>&times;</a>
```

Comment: dylan thank you so much you saved my life thanks ❤❤❤❤

Comment: If this answered your question, then mark the answer as accepted. There is no need to say thanks in the comments :)

Comment: Using `href="javascript:void(0)"` means a `button` should be used instead. --- Also no need to make another function. Just pass it in `onClick={closeNav}`.